# Match values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to return the most common duration from a dataset? I would like to return from column 16:00 the highest values corresponding to the duration column: 30 and 60.

Sample output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Desired output

Duration: 30 60

Sample data

```
structure(list(Duration = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), `16:00` = c(1, 
0, 3, 0, 1, 3), `16:10` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:20` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Duration = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-Duration) %>% slice_max(order_by = value,n = 1) %>% pull(Duration)
[1] 30 60
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking in column `16:00` as stated, this should work just fine.

```r
df$Duration[df$`16:00` == max(df$`16:00`)]
# [1] 30 60
```